# Авторизация и регистрация на стороннем сайте по Open ID

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Разбираюсь с Open API. Вот только не могу понять, как связать со своим сайтом? Как в БД добавить пользователя ВК?

Не понимаю, например, на хэшкоде, после авторизации идет редирект на `../vkontakte/done/` - как сюда передаются данные полученные от Open API?

Comment: Вконтакте нету ОпенИд. Есть OAuth. Записывать нужно сочетание vkontakte и id пользователя.

Схема примерно такая, запрашиваем токен, редиректим пользователя. Пользователь соглашается, и возвращается на сайт, опять спрашиваем вконтакте и получаем данные.

Comment: а как скрипт поймет, что это был именно тот пользователь, который согласился? как он получит его ID? Можете пример показать? Точнее, пример скрипта, который запрашивает ВК повторно данные, куда он посылает запрос, и как он берет ID пользователя. На PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читали? — [Авторизация сайтов](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: xя пропустил эту страницу в доках))) спасибо.